# Change between two classes when using WTForms in FLASK

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms

I am trying to create a simple blog app using flask. This app has a Sign in and a register page.

I specified the forms it uses as follows:

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, SubmitField, BooleanField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Length, Email, EqualTo

class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('Username: ', 
                validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=2, max=20)])
    email = StringField('Email: ',
                validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    password = PasswordField('Password: ',
                validators=[DataRequired()])
    confirm_password = PasswordField('Confirm Password: ',
                validators=[DataRequired(), EqualTo('password')])
    submit = SubmitField('Sign Up')

class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    email = StringField('Email',
                validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    password = PasswordField('Password',
                validators=[DataRequired()])
    remember = BooleanField('Remember me?')
    submit = SubmitField('Login')
```

When I try calling the form for example:

```
<div class="form-group">
                {{ form.password.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                {{ form.password }}
   </div>
```

It will always call the RegistrationForm class.

I want to use ''' {{ form.remember }} ''' from my LoginForm. However I get the error message:

> 'forms.RegistrationForm object' has no attribute 'Loginform'

how do I tell WTforms to look in LoginForm?

Answer (score 0):

The form used in the login.html page needs to be passed in when you define your routes.

```
@app.route("/login", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
return render_template('login.html', title='Login', form=form)
```